# C# Set duration and play sounds stored in an arraylist consecutively

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have the following Play method for playing musical notes stored in an arraylist:

```
public void Play(Duration d){


            int duration = 1;

            if (d == Duration.SemiBreve)
            {
                duration = 16;
            }

            else if (d == Duration.DotMin)
            {
                duration = 10;
            }

            else if (d == Duration.minim)
            {
                duration = 8;
            }

            else if (d == Duration.Crotchet)
            {
                duration = 4;
            }

            else if (d == Duration.Quaver)
            {
                duration = 2;
            }

            else if (d == Duration.SemiQuaver)
            {
                duration = 1;
            }

            player = new SoundPlayer();

            player.SoundLocation = "pathToLocation";


            //set timer
            time = new Timer();
            time.Tick += new EventHandler(clockTick);
            time.Interval = duration * 150;
            player.Play();
            time.Start();

        }
```

When I call the method with a button:

```
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

        //Loops through the collection and plays each note one after the other
        foreach (MusicNote music in this.staff.Notes)
        {
            music.Play(music.Dur)

        }
    }
```

Only the last note gets played. With PlaySync() all the notes get played but the duration isn't recognized. I also tried using threads like so:

```
foreach (MusicNote music in this.staff.Notes)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(playMethod=>music.Play(music.Dur));  
                t.Start();
                t.Join();

            }
```

But it doesn't work either. Any suggestions as to how I can get the files to play consecutively like with PlaySync but using their set duration?

Comment: You'll have to add some logic to play one note at a time. Try getting that to work so it plays just one note after a button click. Then add the timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't wait for the timer anywhere. So in practice all notes get played almost simultaneously, causing just the last one to be effectively audible.

---

UPDATE: Using the `System.Timers.Timer` class the way to go is registering a handler for the `Elapsed` event and playing the notes one-by-one in the event handler. This way you avoid freezing the UI.

Another option is playing in a background thread and the using `Thread.Sleep` to wait. Here you will have to make sure the thread is stopped according to the state of the UI (i.e. the use closes the current dialog etc.).

In either case to avoid race conditions you will have to solve concurrent access to `staff.Notes` or make a copy of it for the sake of playing it.

Comment: So I'm guessing I have to wait for the timer in the button method and not the music.Play method? How do you wait for the timer, so you use timer.Elapsed? Thanks, and please excuse the questions if they are simple but I've never used the timer class before and researching as I go

Comment: I managed to fix it in a very simple way, I set the main thread to sleep for the same time as the timer's interval (until the sound finishes playing) for each note. This worked for my particular needs, but since the whole program gets blocked, could you suggest a better method? Either way your answer led me to the solution, thanks.